# How can I store Object data type in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, talend

I have a kind of object like this:

```
  {{generaladdendumlist: {}, microchip: null, freetext: null, additionalpermerchant: null, telephonecompany: null, passengertransportaddendumlist: {}, merchantinformation: {messagetypeidentifier: '1644', functioncode: '696', messagenumber: '53331800', formatcode: 'AA', forwardingreferencedata: '123456000000', cardacceptorbusinesscode: 5411, name: 'PROVE POS', street: 'VIA ROSSI 2', city: 'VERONA', postalcode: '000000', region: 'VR', countrycode: 'ITA'}, lodgingaddendumlist: {}, carrentaladdendumlist: {}, moneytransfer: null, fleetlist: {}, purchasinglist: {}, dccaddendum: null}}
```

I am retriving it from a Cassandra's table and processing it with Talend Big Data in order to fill my Postgres's table. How can I store it inside my table? I am trying text[] and character varying [], but the field remain empty.

Does anyone could help me, please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to store? What is the meaning of the data? How is the table defined?

Comment: I have 2 Cassandra's column defined as follow:

1) type: Object db_type: varint
2) type: Object db_type: set

I do not know ho to manage them in Talend.

I want to map this field with Talend and insert the data in a 2 corresponding Postgres' table columns. How can I do that? How can I manage varint and set?